# How to make .createElement("image") into a link as well

Tags: javascript, html, image, hyperlink, createelement

I've managed to get the images to list the way I want, now I'd each image to be a link, that points to it's own URL

What it is now:

```
<img src="01.jpg" />
```

What I want it to be:

```
<a href="01.jpg" target="_new"><img src="01.jpg" /></a>
```

Current Code:

```
<script>
  var fullLink = 'http://www.website.com/'; //Public URL
  var ext = ".jpg"; //File Extension 

  for ( var i = 1; i < 6 ; i++ ) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    if (i < 10) {
      link.setAttribute("href", fullLink+"0"+i+ext);
      elem.setAttribute("src", fullLink+"0"+i+ext);
    } else {
      link.setAttribute("href", fullLink+i+ext);
      elem.setAttribute("src", fullLink+i+ext);
    }
      elem.setAttribute("height", "250px");
      document.getElementById("images").appendChild(link);
      document.getElementById("images").appendChild(elem);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Who the heck downvoted this question? This question shows reasonable effort, an attempted solution, the expected output and the current output.  It's well formatted by site standards.  Not every knows everything about javascript or enough to search for when something goes wrong.

Comment: See [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wpsrLmue/) for a solution and a couple other modifications. You shouldn't do the lookup for `document.getElementById("images")` on every loop. Instead, do it once before the `for` and save it as a variable.  There's also easier ways to pad the image number to reduce the cyclomatic complexity and increase the readability.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<script>
  var fullLink = 'http://www.website.com/'; //Public URL
  var ext = ".jpg"; //File Extension 

  for ( var i = 1; i < 6 ; i++ ) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    if (i < 10) {
      link.setAttribute("href", fullLink+"0"+i+ext);
      elem.setAttribute("src", fullLink+"0"+i+ext);
    } else {
      link.setAttribute("href", fullLink+i+ext);
      elem.setAttribute("src", fullLink+i+ext);
    }
      elem.setAttribute("height", "250px");
      link.appendChild(elem);  //<----
      document.getElementById("images").appendChild(link);
  }
</script>
```

This should be what your're looking for. It puts the img you created as a child of the anchored link you created.

No need to append the image to the images ID because it's contained in `link` now.